# Works via Postman but not in Flutter: API call with GCS pre-signed URL

Tags: flutter, dart, postman, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload a video file to GCS using a pre-signed url. I've managed to create the url via Google but now I am facing a problem using it.

Upload works in Postman, got response 200.

[image: postman request headers][postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLMNg.png), [postman params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjX28.png)

Code copied from Postman results in 403 Forbidden (SignatureDoesNotMatch):

```
Future<http.StreamedResponse> uploadVideo(
      {required String uploadURL, required String filePath}) async {
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'};
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('PUT', Uri.parse(uploadURL));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', filePath));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
    return response;
  }
```

This is the error I am getting from Google:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>GOOG4-RSA-SHA256
20210803T082850Z
20210803/auto/storage/goog4_request
6d513846a3db49f949b0d2eea8f04b90f918b3b94588c3ed55ed3620b7d7e1f6</StringToSign><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/phonedo-interviews/app-test/007/2.mp4
X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&amp;X-Goog-Credential=interviews%40interviews-317011.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20210803%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&amp;X-Goog-Date=20210803T082850Z&amp;X-Goog-Expires=900&amp;X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost
content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=dart-http-boundary-6w1yq6BQN3EkGBrhHZnwidOXZsBecsgSwTT3nBjB9vQCToHt0cg
host:storage.googleapis.com

content-type;host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest></Error>
```

Note: I needed `Content-Type` to be `application/octet-stream` so I disabled that header in Postman's automatic headers and added `Content-Type` manually. When I didn't do that I also got 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to send the file in binary.

Here is the working code:

```
  Future<http.Response> uploadVideo(
      {required String uploadURL, required String filePath}) async {
    var response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse(uploadURL),
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'},
      body: File(filePath).readAsBytesSync(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Postman headers, a `Token` is given to GCS (first line). Given that you need authorization, Postman probably has this Token saved somewhere application-wise.

In this flutter code, the headers you're giving do not include an Auth token and therefore you're receiving a 403 error.

Comment: thanks, but I'm using a pre-signed URL that does not require Auth.